# How to paste from MS OneNote to OpenOffice?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, libreoffice-writer, openoffice-writer, microsoft-onenote-2010

No any text, copied to clipboard from `MS OneNote 2010` can be pasted into `Apache OpenOffice 4.0.1` `Writer`.

Even if it is just small fragment of plain text.

Why? And how to fix?

Comment: Sure, it works in any (apparent) program except `Writer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue since 2005](http://www.oooforum.org/forum/viewtopic.phtml?t=16944); OpenOffice Bugzilla has two bug report on this issue, [one from 2005](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=57001) and [one from 2009](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=101024). You may subscribe to the bug reports and vote them up so the issue receives higher priority.

There seems to be no solution up to now, only two workarounds:

- Pasting to OpenOffice / LibreOffice **works if OneNote is closed**, so copy - close OneNote - paste into OpenOffice;
- **Drag&Drop** should work anyway.

Comment: Incredible. What are they thinking about!?

Comment: Same with Microsoft Publisher 2013 + Libreoffice 4.3 on Win7, otherwise Libroffice pops up 'Requested clipboard format is not available.' ..... :S

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other workaround without closing OneNote:

- Mark the word or words, the whole chapter or an entire window or all
  windows on the OneNote page and and copy to clipboard (Ctrl-C).
- Open WordPad, insert/paste from clipboard (Ctrl-V).
- Than copy and paste from there to LibreOffice Writer (Ctrl-C,Ctrl-V).

Looks like that this kills all the strange formats and keeps only the plain text, which we want in Writer. I didn´t test it with OOWriter, but it should work.